# Flutter code to display the firebase data in listview or in listbuilder

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am developing an app in which I need to display all the lecturer details which is stored in Firebase using `list_view`. I have used `list_builder` for that. I am getting the same data in all the list view that means all tile contains same lecturer id.

[image]

[image]

i tried to upload screenshot but i could not upload it

**output:**
***1: variable exist :***

```
{LEC02: {EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC02, NAME: VIGNESH, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LEC02, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: BCOM, DOJ: 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000}, LEC04: {EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC04, NAME: KARTHIK, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LEC04, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: MCOM, DOJ: 2018-12-26 00:00:00.000}}
```

***2: variable key_id:***

```
(LEC02, LEC04, LECTURER 01, LEC03, LEC01)
```

***3: variable data:***

```
({EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC02, NAME: VIGNESH, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LEC02, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: BCOM, DOJ: 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000}, {EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC04, NAME: KARTHIK, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LEC04, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: MCOM, DOJ: 2018-12-26 00:00:00.000}, {EMAIL: , SEX: FEMALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LECTURER 01, NAME: AA, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LECTURER 01, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: KAAM, DOJ: 2018-12-25 00:00:00.000}, {EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC03, NAME: PRANEETH, POSITION: HOD, PASSWORD: LEC03, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: MCA, DOJ: 2018-12-25 00:00:00.000}, {EMAIL: , SEX: MALE, ADDRESS: , MOBILE: , ID: LEC01, NAME: NISHA, POSITION: LECTURER, PASSWORD: LEC01, PHOTO: , QUALIFICATION: MCOM, DOJ: 2018-12-26 00:00:00.000})
```

#### Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';

import '../slidelecturer.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

String lecturer_id,lecturer_name;
bool hasdata=true;
Map<dynamic,dynamic> exist;
Iterable<dynamic>key_id,data;
Widget body;


final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

class viewlecturer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _viewlecturerState createState() => _viewlecturerState();
}

class _viewlecturerState extends State<viewlecturer> {

 @override
 void initState(){
   print("hello");

  this.get_data();

 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(hasdata==false){
      body=new Container(

      child:Center(
        child: Text("LECTURER DOSE NOT EXIST",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),

     ));
    }
     if(hasdata==true){
       body= new Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: exist==null?0:exist.length,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
           return Card(
             child: new Text("${key_id}"),

           );
         },

       ),);}

    return body;

  }


   Future<String>get_data()async {

      database
          .reference()
          .child("NITTE/LECTURER").orderByValue()
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) async {
            this.setState((){
              exist = snapshot.value;
            });

        if (exist == null) {
          setState(() {
            hasdata=false;      
                    });

            // confirmation();
        } else if (exist != null) {
          setState(() {
            hasdata=true; 

            key_id=exist.keys;
            data=exist.values;

          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a StreamBuilder and provide snapshots from your database as the stream and return your listview in the builder. This allows for your listview to keep refreshing so your user will always have updated data.